# BibTeX problem reading .bib source file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to use BibTeX, but the result of this code is that it prints the Bibliography headline and does not display what's inside the `sample.bib` file.
Does someone recognize any mistake? Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % put subsubsections in ToC
    \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\ensuremath{\blacktriangleright}} % no number, fancy glyph
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{15pt}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,bold-extra,geometry,
    amssymb,amsmath,mathtools, microtype,url}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true, hidelinks, pdftitle={
THE MANAGEMENT AND PRICING OF WEATHER DERIVATIVES:The case of an HDD Call Option},
pdfauthor={Alessandro Pipitone}]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{headings}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% New Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lstset{ 
    language=Matlab,
    numbers=left, 
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,  stepnumber=1,                               numbersep=5pt,backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    showspaces=false,   showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                         frame=single,              
    tabsize=2,captionpos=b,
    breaklines=true,       
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)}  
}
%
\newcommand{\intentblankpage}{
%     Leaves a blank page
    \newpage
    \null
    \vfill
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
         \textit{This page intentionally left blank.}
        %\textit{Questa pagina \`e lasciata intenzionalmente bianca.}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
}
\def\mclimits_#1{\limits_{\mathclap{#1}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End New Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \input{./titlepage}
    \intentblankpage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter*{Introduction} \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}  
    \label{CH:Intro}
    \input{./introduzione}

    \chapter{The Weather as a Source of Risk}
    \label{CH:Teoria}
    \input{./capI}

    \chapter{Inside the Market: How to Manage Risk Weather}
    \label{CH:Val_num}
    \input{./capII}

    \chapter{Forecasting and Pricing models: A Focus on Temperature}
    \label{CH:Val_num}
    \input{./capIII}

    \chapter{Numerical Implementation of Pricing Models}
    \label{CH:Val_num}
    \input{./capIV}

    \chapter*{Conclusion} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}  
    \label{CH:Intro}
    \input{./conclusioni}

     \chapter*{Appendix A} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}  
    \label{CH:Intro}
    \input{./Appendix}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{sample}


    %\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

My bib file looks like this

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

Comment: Added all I have in my bib file

Comment: You don't load `biblatex`  in your preamble, and you use the syntax of `bibtex`!

Comment: My aim is to have a list of books, articles and website at the end of the document, without pointing at the text. The citations in the text I did it with \footnote command

Comment: @Bernard If I upload biblatex with the usepackage command, it gives error and nothing is displayed

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following MWE. I added your given bib file to it with package `filecontents`.

Please see that you have to change the order of your used packages. Do not load packages twice.

Because we do not have your `\input`ed files I added `\nocite{*}` to get all bib entrys printed in the bibliography.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % number subsubsections
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % put subsubsections in ToC
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\ensuremath{\blacktriangleright}} % no number, fancy glyph
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{csquotes} % <===============================================
%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{15pt}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\usepackage{graphicx} % <=======================================
\usepackage{%
% fixltx2e,
  bold-extra,
% geometry,
  amssymb,mathtools, microtype,url
}
\usepackage[%
  bookmarks=true, hidelinks, 
  pdftitle={THE MANAGEMENT AND PRICING OF WEATHER DERIVATIVES:The case of an HDD Call Option},
  pdfauthor={Alessandro Pipitone}
]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{headings}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% New Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lstset{ 
    language=Matlab,
    numbers=left, 
    numberstyle=\footnotesize,  stepnumber=1,                               numbersep=5pt,backgroundcolor=\color{white},
    showspaces=false,   showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                         frame=single,              
    tabsize=2,captionpos=b,
    breaklines=true,       
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)}  
}
%
\newcommand{\intentblankpage}{
%     Leaves a blank page
    \newpage
    \null
    \vfill
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
         \textit{This page intentionally left blank.}
        %\textit{Questa pagina \`e lasciata intenzionalmente bianca.}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
}
\def\mclimits_#1{\limits_{\mathclap{#1}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% End New Commands %%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%   \input{./titlepage}
    \intentblankpage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter*{Introduction} \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}  
    \label{CH:Introc}
%   \input{./introduzione}

    \chapter{The Weather as a Source of Risk}
    \label{CH:Teoria}
%   \input{./capI}

    \chapter{Inside the Market: How to Manage Risk Weather}
    \label{CH:Val_num}
%   \input{./capII}

    \chapter{Forecasting and Pricing models: A Focus on Temperature}
    \label{CH:Val_numa}
%   \input{./capIII}

    \chapter{Numerical Implementation of Pricing Models}
    \label{CH:Val_numb}
%   \input{./capIV}

    \chapter*{Conclusion} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}  
    \label{CH:Intro}
%   \input{./conclusioni}

     \chapter*{Appendix A} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix A}  
    \label{CH:Introb}
%   \input{./Appendix}

\nocite{*} % <==========================================================
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

    %\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

and the resulting bibliography:

[image]